# Cannot resolve hostname

Tags: networking, server, dns

5 PCs, all running Ubuntu, connected by  a wireless to router with DNS. Running an ejabberd server on one of the PCs, and an Apache server on another. PC 1 can only connect to the servers with their IP addresses, not their names (so I can't set up a Jabber account on it). All of the other computers are resolving the hostnames without difficulty.

Here are the pertinent files:

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

---

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   nameofPC1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

---

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

---

Firewall: I've never used ufw on this machine. When I run `iptables -L` this is what I get:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Operation not permitted
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

---

Also, ping works for IP address but not for `hostname.local`.  `nslookup` can't find anything, whether it is IP or hostname (but that's also true of the machines that aren't having problems resolving the hostname).

Any suggestions?

This is a problem only for LAN hostnames, e.g., servername.local. Internet hostnames (google.com) are resolved.

I understand that I can set up a local DNS server, but my router already performs that function, and all of the other PCs on the LAN are resolving hostnames without difficulty. What I can't figure our is why this one PC, out of all the rest, can't resolve hostnames.

Comment: What's in /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf ? Try manually adding a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to it and ping google.com again. Restart network manager just in case too, if just straight editing of the file fails

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are talking specifically about LAN/mDNS hostnames (like server.local), or external qualified hostnames (like google.com) as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set up name resolution inside a LAN i can think of 2 options:

**1. Set up a DNS-server**

Run: `sudo apt-get install named` on one of the servers, configure the DNS-server and point to that server by editing `/etc/resolv.conf` or using `resolvconf` if that's what you use.

**2 . edit `/etc/hosts`**

Simply edit this file and add the ip-address & desired name.
This has to be done on each machine individually.